# How can you check if an instance variable is set when you have a symbol representing the instance variable?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to use `remove_instance_variable(instance_variable)`, where `instance_variable` contains a Symbol of the form `:@some_variable`, but first I want to verify that the instance variable (e.g. `@some_variable` exists.

`defined? instance_variable` will of course return "local-variable", so that does me no good.

Even if I could grab the contents of `instance_variable`, to effectively use `defined? :@some_variable` that would return "expression" because it's telling me that the symbol is defined.  (All symbols, even which you've never used before, will return "expression" in this context.)

If I use `eval`, then the symbol gets conveniently replaced by the actual instance variable, and it works, returning either `nil` or "instance-variable".

```
eval("defined? #{instance_variable}")
```

*But* given the strong aversion towards `eval` (which is of course justified in cases where the variable may contain user-submitted values), I'd rather find a different solution, if possible.  Even if I thoroughly ensure that there's no possibility of `instance_variable` containing any user-submitted data, everyone who looks at the code after me is going to stop and ask "why is `eval` being used here?".

Is there another way to check if the instance variable referred to by the symbol inside `instance_variable` is defined?

Comment: See [`Object#instance_variable_defined?`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_defined-3F)

Comment: @Stefan: thanks!  can you give that as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object` implements 5 methods for getting, setting, checking, listing, and removing instance variables:

- [`Object#instance_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) – returns the value of an instance variable
- [`Object#instance_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) – sets the value of an instance variable
- [`Object#instance_variable_defined?`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_defined-3F) - checks if an instance variable is defined
- [`Object#instance_variables`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables) – returns an array of all instance variable names
- [`Object#remove_instance_variable`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-remove_instance_variable) – removes an instance variable

`instance_variable_defined?` is what you are looking for:

```
name = :@foo
instance_variable_defined?(name) #=> false

@foo = nil
instance_variable_defined?(name) #=> true
```

The method is also useful for implementing memoization of values that could be `nil`:

```
def foo
  return @foo if instance_variable_defined?(:@foo)
  
  @foo = expensive_operation_that_could_return_nil
end
```